# Arrange the following functions according to the order (rate of growth) from lowest to highest

Tags: asymptotics, computer-science

**Arrange the following functions according to the order (rate of growth) from lowest to highest. If any two or more are of the same order, indicate which. (Two functions f, g are of the same order if f = Θ(g);f has order not greater than g if f = O(g).)**

**NOTE:(ln n stands for the natural logarithm of n and lg n stands for the base-2 logarithm of n.)**

$n$

$n^2 + \lg n$

$\lg n$

$\ln \ln n$

$n^2$

$\lg^2 n$

$\ln n$

$n^3$

$n^2 \lg n$

So I think I'm doing this right. Hopefully someone can verify my work..Here is what I have:

1.$n$ = $O(n)$

2.$n^2 + \log n$ = $O(n^2)$

3.$\lg n = O(\lg n)$

4.$\ln \ln n = O(\ln n)$

5.$n^2 = O(n^2)$

6.$\lg^2 n = O(\lg^2 n)$

7.$\ln n = O(\ln n )$

8.$n^3 = O(n^3)$

9.$n^2 \lg n = O(n^2 \lg n)$

So in order from **lowest** to **highest** I have:

$\ln n$

$n$

$\lg^2 n$

$n^2$

$n^2 \lg n$

$n^3$

Comment: I don't think $\log(\log x) = O(\log x)$

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen But it is.